# Vue.js VUEX property undefined issue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I got interesting bug. Chrome's console says that property 'name' is undefined but Vue tool is showing that getters are working properly. Images below...[image]

and here is my Vue tool. Look at the getters. 
[image]

also here is my code for store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
import { api } from "./api_key";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  data: "",
  location: "New York"
},
mutations: {
  GET_DATA(state, data) {
    state.data = data;
  }
},
actions: {
  getData({ commit, state }) {
    console.log(api);
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=${
          state.location
         }&appid=${api}&units=metric&cnt=5`
      )
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data) {
          commit("GET_DATA", response.data);
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
},
getters: {
  city(state) {
    return state.data.city.name;
  }
}
});
```

and code of the component

```
export default {
    methods:{
        selectCity(){
            if(this.city==""){
                return this.city="New York"
            }
        }
    },
    computed:{
        getLocation(){
            return this.$store.getters.city;
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you don't have `city.name` only `city:"New York"` in DevTools.

Comment: You need to show your codes in `MySearchbar.vue` its the one causing the error.

Comment: last chunk is for MySearchbar.vue

Comment: Its the JS /script only. The HTML (or "Template") is also needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial state

```
state: {
  data: "",
  location: "New York"
}
```

sets `data` to an empty string. This is most probably what's producing the error due to

```
state.data.city.name
```

where `city` is undefined on a `String`.

Set your initial state `data` to something that's not going to cause errors before your async data has loaded

```
data: {
  city: {
    name: ''
  }
}
```

---

Alternatively (and because the above appears to mess up your other logic), change your *getter* to be forgiving of empty data

```
getters: {
  city (state) {
    return state.data.city && state.data.city.name || ''
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to set it to null. Didn't work. also tried to remove "location" property at all. Same thing

Comment: @UlukbekAbylbekov I think I got it wrong first time and have updated my answer

Comment: initial data in my component?

Comment: No, your initial `state` in Vuex

Comment: @UlukbekAbylbekov So what's the error now? What does your code look like now?

Comment: It worked. But in that data I have another values in object that I want to use beside the city.name

Comment: @UlukbekAbylbekov I don't understand your comment. You said it didn't work and now it does? Your first draft had `data` set to an empty string so setting it to a near-empty object should not make a difference to other application logic.

Comment: It is working. But I don't know how to organize my state now

Comment: @UlukbekAbylbekov I've added another option but I don't think it's optimal

Comment: Anyway I got what is the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there anyway to keep fetched data in my "data" property and get values from "data" object one by one as I tried before?

Comment: @UlukbekAbylbekov I really don't know what you're asking. When your `getData` action completes, it commits an entirely new `data` property to your state. I don't know what you mean by _"keep fetched data"_. Perhaps you need to open a new question