# Pass data from Vuex getter to component prop

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'd like to pull a collection of data from Vuex config state and pass to a prop of a component that will use it to populate an autocomplete. I cannot figure out the syntax for doing it.

With my attempts below I'm not able to build. Do I need to move the prop to data within the parent and pass?

Config data is as follows: 
`{"permissions":[{"permission":"ADMIN_ACCOUNT", "permissionName":"Account Admin"}, ...]}`

Here's my latest attempt:

**Module**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
    config: []
}

const getters = {
    getConfig: state => state.config
}

const actions = {
    async getConfig({ commit }) {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/config')
        commit('setConfig', response.data)
    }
}

const mutations = {
    setConfig: (state, config) => (state.config = config)
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

**Parent component**

```
<MyComponent
    //:permissions="this.getConfig['permissions']"
    //:permissions="this.getConfig().permissions"
    //etc
...
computed: mapGetters(["getConfig"]),
...
```

**Child component**

```
...
props: {
    permissions: [],
...
```

Comment: Just `:permissions="getConfig.permissions"` should work but note that a) your initial state `config` should be an object, not an array, and b) `permissions` will not be defined until your Axios request completes. Perhaps initialise your state with `config: { permissions: [] }` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js VUEX property undefined issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914984/vue-js-vuex-property-undefined-issue)

Comment: Changing `permissions`  in the module as an object as you suggested corrects the issue: `config: { permissions: [] }`.

Comment: How can I avoid the child component losing the permissions prop on a page refresh?

Answer (score -1):

You could just map the state directly without the need for a getter.

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({permissions: state => state.moduleName.config.permissions})
}
```

And then just pass the `permissions` to the component prop.

```
<MyComponent :permissions="permissions" />
```

Default permission needs to be set on the module as @Phil commented.